# I want to make relation between two table which has array data(postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table department(
   deptname text NOT NULL,
   deptnum integer NOT NULL,
   avgsalary integer,
   member text[],
   constraint pk_department primary key(deptnum)
 );

 create table employee(
   empname text NOT NULL,
   empnum integer NOT NULL,
   spot text,
   entrydate Date NOT NULL,
   livinglocation text NOT NULL,
   constraint pk_employee primary key(empnum)
 );
```

I made this two table. I want to make relation, 1 department has many employee. So I made member array in department table. But, It allows to add emploee data which is not exist in employee table. I want to push employee name into department table which is exist in employee table. How to make this kind of relationship??

Comment: Create a properly normalized model and you won't have problems defining foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually employees belong to only one department.  This is handled by putting a foreign key reference in the `employee` table:

```
create table department(
   deptname text NOT NULL,
   deptnum integer NOT NULL,
   avgsalary integer,
   constraint pk_department primary key(deptnum)
 );

 create table employee (
   empname text NOT NULL,
   empnum integer NOT NULL,
   spot text,
   entrydate Date NOT NULL,
   livinglocation text NOT NULL,
   depnum int,
   constraint fk_employee_department foreign key (depnum) references department(depnum),
   constraint pk_employee primary key(empnum)
 );
```

If employees can be in multiple departments, then you would want another table, `employeeDepartments` with one row per employee and per department.